# Lottie files return a 403 Error in production

Tags: angular, animation, lottie

I'm using Lottie animations in my website. In local environment all of them work perfectly. However, in production there are some animations that fail. When I open those JSON files I read the following message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>ID_VALUE</RequestId>
<HostId>HOST_ID_VALUE</HostId>
</Error>
```

In console I get a 403 Error of these files.

I'm looking for possible solutions but I don't know how to solve this issue.

I tried to publish again these files in production but I still see the same error.